# Installing linux-generic-lts-quantal in 12.04.3 via preseed

Tags: 12.04, kernel, preseed

I'm struggling with getting this working. The problem is, the backported raring kernel breaks OVS. So we need the quantal kernel.

I've tried this in my preseed:

```
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image  string linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

but it doesn't work since, according to debconf-get-selections --installer, the only versions available are:

```
$ debconf-get-selections --installer | grep linux-image
# Choices: linux-signed-generic-lts-raring,linux-generic-lts-raring,linux-signed-image-    
  generic-lts-raring,linux-image-generic-lts-raring,linux-signed-image-3.8.0-29-
  generic,linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic, none
```

I do see this kernel still available in precise-security. I've tried these stanza's to try and pull in the upstream package

```
# Mirror Settings
d-i mirror/suite string precise
d-i mirror/udeb/suite string precise-security
d-i mirror/protocol string http
d-i mirror/udeb/components multiselect main
d-i mirror/http/directory  string /ubuntu

d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu

d-i mirror/http/proxy       string
```

But getting the same result.

*edit*

I'd add that if I insert a proxy server into the equation, even the most minimal mirror config will pull in the correct kernel.